# Cannot read property of undefined (mongoDB, node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, docker-compose, database-connection

I initialize the connection as follows:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let uri;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod'){
    console.log("running in prod");
    uri = 'mongodb://[IP-Adress]:27017/';
} else {
    console.log("running in dev");
    uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
}

let isConnectionInitialized = false;
let client;

async function initializeConnection() {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    isConnectionInitialized = true;
}
```

Now, when I call 'insertOne()' for example like this:

```
async function createXY(param1, param2, param3) {
if(!isConnectionInitialized){await initializeConnection();}
await client.db('xy').collection('xy').insertOne({
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2,
    param3: param3
}, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return param1;
});
return 0;
```

}

It worked on localhost (and still works), but on the deployed version theres an error.
I get the following message from the logs of docker-compose:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertOne' of undefined

Now, I'm not sure whether I understood the concept of connecting to mongoDB completely or not, but I think there's my mistake somewhere yet I can't figure it out. I also figure that it could have to do with my understanding of async/await.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding async/await - you should not mix `callbacks` and `async/await` as you did in `createXY()`. You can simply remove the callback and handle it as follows:

```
async function createXY(param1, param2, param3) {
    if (!isConnectionInitialized) {
        await initializeConnection();
    }

    await client.db('xy').collection('xy').insertOne({
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2,
        param3: param3
    });

}
```

Regarding the undefined `collection` - if the code works fine on your local machine, one possiblity could be that the collection does not exist yet on your production server and the MongoDB-user does not have the required `createCollection`-[role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#createCollection) in order to auto-create it.